# LaTeX, sloped boxes

Tags: latex, box

I'd like to make a Find-A-Word for the library wall.

The solution (also for the wall) requires a box, enclosing the word.

Horizontal/vertical boxes are no problem. Sloped (slanted?) boxes are what's the problem.\I envisage a command like
\makebox (length, breadth, angle, co-ordinates of left-lower corner)

It may be that this has been done before.

Has anyone any suggestions?

William.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tikz` and the `tikzmarks` library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily
\noindent
\tikzmark{a:start}w d e w e r n \tikzmark{b:start}b v c w o i q\tikzmark{b:stop} v o i q t u h n r g j q v r o e q i o n j v k w 
o q p i n t o j v k m o q e i n g k m f o r q e p i n k f m p i g n o j k m 
f \tikzmark{c:start}v e p o q i o n j r g k m l e v q n b g j k v m e q n b o j g k v l m e q 
n b j g f k l e m v q n j g k e m l v q n g j r f e l v q n j g f l k q g j 
n\tikzmark{a:stop} v q e\tikzmark{c:stop} n p m k w g j k n e k e m l v q n g j r f e l v q n j g f l k q g j 


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red] ([shift={(0,1.5ex)}]pic cs:a:start) rectangle (pic cs:a:stop);

\draw[red] ([shift={(0,1.5ex)}]pic cs:b:start) rectangle (pic cs:b:stop);

\draw[red,rotate=45] ([shift={(1.5ex,1.5ex)}]pic cs:c:start) rectangle ([shift={(-0.5ex,0ex)}]pic cs:c:stop);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]